# AWS elastic beanstalk default permission policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS elastic beanstalk and my permission policy of elastic beanstalk seems messed up.

What is the default permission policy of AWS elastic beanstalk ?

What permission policy of AWS elastic beanstalk shall I use to access IAM SSL certificate in order to open https?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Which permission policy are you referring to?

Comment: In a new AWS account, if we start elastic beanstalk then the role aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role will be automatically created in IAM. What is the default permission policy of aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role (power user? read-only user? etc. ) ?  Shall Power User permission be able to access IAM SSL certificate for https secure connection?

Comment: This account by default is not a power user. This role will have some permissions required to use elasticbeanstalk. You can log in to the IAM console and check the policy that has been configured for your role. This page gives some guidelines on what policies you can use: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.roles.aeb.html#AWSHowTo.iam.policies.actions.roles
You can tweak the policy per your requirement.